# What am I? (First riddle :)

Tags: riddle

> This is my first riddle, please give me feedback. I would also be interested in a better way of presentation, like choice of words or even a rhyme scheme because I'm no native speaker :)

```
What am I?

I can float although I am made of metal.

I am sent out although noone wants to meet me.

I want to meet someone although then I would never float again.
```

Comment: title: Do you mean "(first riddle :))" ? (;-))

Comment: @palsch [xkcd.com/541](http://xkcd.com/541)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a

> Naval Mine

I can float although I am made of metal.

> They can float in water

I am sent out although noone wants to meet me.

> No one wants to come across a mine ...

I want to meet someone although then I would never float again.

> It is a mines purpose to explode on contact, but it could not float after doing so (what's left of it would sink).

Comment: gah, I was in the process of typing that, you beat me to it :P

Answer (score 2):

My guess is:

> Hydrogen  
>  1. Hydrogen is a metal. 
>  2. It is emitted by processes, but can be hazardous. 
>  3. When bound to another element, it is no longer a (floating) gas.

Comment: It is a metal, but it is not really made of metal, is it? Good answer though, it went to a totally different direction I was intending.

Comment: It's not *really* a metal. There is the so-called "metallic hydrogen," but really, hydrogen is just hydrogen.